# Custom Code Mobile View Slider not working in iphone and well supported in Android

Tags: magento-1.9, php, css

My Code :

```
<div>
    <center><pre style="
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #166fb0;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-top-width: 0px;">
<b><th>QUICK LINKS -> </th></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>
<th><a href="abc.net/" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#54b016'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#166fb0'" style="color: #166fb0;"> MULTI-PURPOSE RACK </a></th></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>
<th><a href="abc.net/" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#54b016'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#166fb0'"   style="color: #166fb0;"   >PUJA LAMPS</a></th></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>
<th><a href= "abc.net/" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#54b016'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#166fb0'" style="color: #166fb0;"> RETURN GIFTS </a></th></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>
<th><a href= "abc.net/" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#54b016'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#166fb0'" style="color: #166fb0;"> SPECIAL POOJA PACKS </a></th></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>
<th><a href= "abc.net/" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#54b016'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#166fb0'" style="color: #166fb0;"> GYA </a></th></b>
</pre>
</center>
</div>
```

Android Output:

[image]

iPhone Output:

[image]

How can i solve this UI Error?

Comment: Slider appearing or not?

Comment: @RameshS No, see above iphone screen shot

Comment: One of the issues is that none of the HTML is valid. The <center> tag has been obsolete for almost 20 years (since 1998) and <th> tags can only be used within <table> tags (th stands for table heading)

Comment: @AndrewNoble so what i need to do?

Comment: @zus I've provided updated HTML and CSS in my answer below, as well as tested it on both iOS and Android.

Comment: @AndrewNoble its working,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some changes and cleaned up your code a bit.

Instead of putting the CSS inline, I've moved it into its own `<style>` tag and changed it to work on both Android and iOS.

Rather than using javascript for the hover effect (which is unnecessary) I've added CSS to do it instead `.quick-links li a:hover`.

Lastly, instead of using `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` for spacing I've added a right margin to each list item.

You might still want to tweak the CSS slightly (spacing, margins etc.), but I've tested that the slider works on both an iPhone 5s, as well as a Nexus 6.

```
<div class="quick-links">
    <ul>
        <li>QUICK LINKS -></li>
        <li><a href="abc.net/">MULTI-PURPOSE RACK</a></li>
        <li><a href="abc.net/">PUJA LAMPS</a></li>
        <li><a href="abc.net/">RETURN GIFTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="abc.net/">SPECIAL POOJA PACKS</a></li>
        <li><a href="abc.net/">GYA</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<style>
    .quick-links {
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 15px;
        color: #166fb0;
        padding: 5px 0;
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }

    .quick-links::after {
        content: ' ';
        display: block;
        clear: both;
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
    }

    .quick-links ul {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .quick-links li {
        display: inline-block;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 25px 0 0;
    }

    .quick-links li:last-child {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    .quick-links li a {
        color: #166fb0;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .quick-links li a:hover {
        color: #54b016;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please give a try to below code if it helps:

```
<div style="
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 0px;
font-size: 15px;
color: #166fb0;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-top: 5px;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-top-width: 0px;">
<th><b>QUICK LINKS -> </b></th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<th><a href="abc.net/" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#54b016'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#166fb0'" style="color: #166fb0;"> <b>MULTI-PURPOSE RACK </b></a></th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<th><a href="abc.net/" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#54b016'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#166fb0'"   style="color: #166fb0;"   ><b>PUJA LAMPS</b></a></th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<th><a href= "abc.net/" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#54b016'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#166fb0'" style="color: #166fb0;"><b> RETURN GIFTS </b></a></th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<th><a href= "abc.net/" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#54b016'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#166fb0'" style="color: #166fb0;"><b> SPECIAL POOJA PACKS</b> </a></th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<th><a href= "abc.net/" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#54b016'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#166fb0'" style="color: #166fb0;"><b>GYA </b></a></th>
</div>
```

Comment: it's not working, an android view also getting an error.